# Socket.io emit callback not firing on server side?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My server emits events properly, but the emit callback never works.  In the following, nothing is logged on my console:

Server:

```
io.sockets.emit('delete hint', {id: id}, function(data){
                    console.log('callback');
                });
```

Client:

```
socket.on('delete hint', function(data){
    // display a message before deleting
    $('#' + data.id).fadeOut(function(){ 
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

I've also tried the client side code as function(data, fn) in case the callback needed to be included on the receiving function.

I'm using windows and my command prompt shows the following when socket.io is emitting the event:

```
websocket writing 5:::{"name":"delete hint", "args":[{"id":"1"}, null]}
```

I can't figure out what the problem is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you've got only one client to reach you could emit only to it instead of emitting in "broadcast" (io.sockets.emit emits to everyone), doing `io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {socket.emit....}`: in this way the callback will be called

Answer (score 5):

A callback is executed on the sender computer when the receiver computer calls it

Have a look at this code:

**Server:**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', connectionFunc);

function connectionFunc (socket) {
    socket.emit('delete hint', "data for client", callThis);
}

//this function is executed when client calls it
function callThis (dataFromClient){

    console.log("Call back fired: " + dataFromClient);
}
```

**Client:**

```
    socket.on('delete hint', function(data, callback) {

        console.log("i received: "+ data);
        // call back will fire only when u the next line runs
        callback("the callThis function on server will run");            

    });
```

You can do this the opposite way.

Comment: I tried this. I can't get the callback to make it to the client. If I `console.log(arguments)` in the event listener on the client it seems that the callback isn't even being passed to the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the callback.

```
socket.on('delete hint', function(data, cb){
    // display a message before deleting
    $('#' + data.id).fadeOut(function(){ 
        $(this).remove();
        cb(null, 'done');
    });
});
```

Comment: The issue seams to be the `io.sockets.emit` I made a test: http://runnable.com/UU9cGTW8r6IwABzk

Comment: Ahh.  I just tried it out with socket.broadcast.emit and it doesn't work with that either.  After some snooping around I found out this is a known issue with socket.io: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/770